# C++ Error: Not declared in scope; Member function

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, compiler-errors

I have a an error for 'Result Vector' was not declared in this scope. I am not sure of where to or how to declare this? The intention of the Result Vector is the show the result of adding the X's of vectors and the Y's of each vector and then return result_vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class vector{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    //Constructor - default
    vector() : x(0), y(0) {}
    //Constructor - Custom
    vector(double xx, double yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
    //Get X & Y Coordinates
    double get_x() { return x;
    }
    double get_y() { return y;
    }
    //Set X & Y Coordinates
    void set_x( double xx) { x = xx;
    }
    void set_y( double yy) { y = yy;
    }
    //Adding Vectors
    vector add_vector( vector v1, vector v2){ 
        result_vector.x = v1.x + v2.x;
        result_vector.y = v1.y + v2.y;
        return result_vector; 
    }
    //Subtracting Vectorsed
    vector subtract_vector( vector v1, vector v2){
        result_vector.x = v1.x - v2.x;
        result_vector.y = v1.y - v2.y;
        return result_vector;
    }
};

int main() {
    //Default
    vector test;
    cout <<"Default \n" test.get_x().get_y() << "\n";
    //Customer
    vector test2(10, 12);
    cout <<"Custom \n" test2.get_x().get_y() << "\n";
    //Adding
    vector add = vector.add_vector(vector test1&, vector test2&);
    cout <<"Adding \n" add.get_x().get_y() <<"\n";
    //Subtracting
    vector sub = vector.subtract_vector(vector test1&, vector test2&);
    cout <<"Subtracting \n" sub.get_x().get_y() <<"\n";

    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory.

- You need to declare result_vector before its first use.
- You can't pass the class name along with object name as arguments.
- Assuming this statement `cout <<"Default \n" test.get_x().get_y() << "\n";` is supposed to print the x and y values of vector, you will have to call `get_x()` and `get_y()` separately.
- Also as mentioned by Andreas DM you can't use `using namespace std;` because it conflicts with the existing class vector.vector class after making the corrections

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>

  class vector{
  private:
      double x;
      double y;
  public:
      //Constructor - default
      vector() : x(0), y(0) {}
      //Constructor - Custom
      vector(double xx, double yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
      //Get X & Y Coordinates
      double get_x() { return x;
      }
      double get_y() { return y;
      }
      //Set X & Y Coordinates
      void set_x( double xx) { x = xx;
      }
      void set_y( double yy) { y = yy;
      }
      //Adding Vectors
      vector add_vector( vector v2){ 
          vector result_vector;
          result_vector.x = x + v2.x;
          result_vector.y = y + v2.y;
          return result_vector; 
      }
      //Subtracting Vectorsed
      vector subtract_vector( vector v2){
          vector result_vector;
          result_vector.x = x - v2.x;
          result_vector.y = y - v2.y;
          return result_vector;
      }
  };

  int main() {
      //Default
      vector test;
      std::cout <<"Default \n" <<test.get_x()<<test.get_y() << "\n";
      //Customer
      vector test2(10, 12);
      std::cout <<"Custom \n" <<test2.get_x()<<test2.get_y() << "\n";
      //Adding
      vector add;
      add = test.add_vector(test2);
      std::cout <<"Adding \n" <<add.get_x()<<add.get_y() <<"\n";
      //Subtracting
      vector sub ;
      sub = test.subtract_vector(test2);
     std::cout <<"Subtracting \n"<< sub.get_x()<<sub.get_y() <<"\n";

      return 0;


  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared `result_vector` it doesn't exist, hence the error.

Also, you're `using namespace std;` and you've named a class `vector`.
therefore the reference to `vector` is ambiguous.

Your code has several other errors, I suggest you use a debugger and go through the errors

Answer (score 0):

Before you use a variable, you have to **declare** it, so that the compiler knows it exits. In C++ this is required (some languages, like Python, don't require it), and so declare `result_vector` first before you use it (`vector result_vector;`)

Comment: Once he fixes that, his next problem is that vector's x and y are private and he's trying to access them directly.

Comment: @mock_blatt That's ok, because the class has access to them, even if it's another variable (because it's the same type).

Comment: Yup you're right. His next problem will be the incorrect use of multiple function calls, right? (I incorrectly called that operator chaining)

Comment: Thanks. So what would I declare for a type for result_vector, is it a double for would it be as if I type result_vector; the compiler is looking for a type? @Blitz Rakete

Comment: Thanks! I see from the above code. So I need to embed the result_vector under the function for adding / subtracting. This makes sense but didn't realize I could. I thought I would have needed to have a separate line above the adding /subtracting vectors such as                                             `vector result_vector;
    //Adding Vectors
    vector add_vector( vector v2){ 
        result_vector.x = x + v2.x;
        result_vector.y = y + v2.y;
        return result_vector; 
    }` @Blitz Rakete